# How to use Conditional interface in spring boot with value inside a list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have application-sample.YAML file where I have data. After loading the data, based on certain fields.  I want to decide which few components to load or not to load. I can see this below condition class loads first, as a result, I am getting the data null because this condition class is loading first before my Data loaded.

```
@Configuration
public class AwsCondition implements Condition {
    
    @Autowired
    MyTestData data;
    
    @Override       
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("inside...........condition");
        if(data.getListeners().size()>1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

MyTestData.java

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class MyTestData implements InitializingBean {

List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    public static class Listener {
        private String type;
        private String name;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        
        if (this.getListeners().isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Nothing  configured. Please verify application-test.yml is configured properly.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

ConditionTest class

```
@Component
@Conditional(AwsCondition.class)
public class TestS3ListenerRouter extends RouteBuilder {
 //My all logic lying here
}
```

Comment: What is `MyTestData` class and how is a bean of this type created? You will need to add more code to your question so that we can help you.

Comment: @JoãoDias I have added the class MyTestData loaded.

Comment: @JDGuide were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
@Component
public class AwsCondition implements Condition {
    
    @Autowired
    MyTestData data;
    
    @Override       
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log.info("inside...........condition");
        if(data.getListeners().size()>1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error, what you changed ?  I have tried with @component also. Its giving nullpointer error ( data.getListeners().)

Comment: And what is `null`? `data` or the result of the `data.getListeners()` call?

Comment: yeah. This condition is loaded first. The Data is not loaded yet.

Comment: Where is the condition being used? Can you add the code?

Comment: @JoãoDias could you please answer this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318794/how-to-autowire-a-bean-inside-a-spring-condition-class