# How to autowire a bean inside a Spring @Condition class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring5

I have an interface `IInterface.java` like below:

```
public interface IInterface {
    void printIt();
}
```

And there are two implementation classes for this: `ImplementationA.java` and `ImplementationB.java`

```
@Component
public class ImplementationA implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationA");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ImplementationB implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationB");
    }
}
```

Now I have a listener class, which has this `IInterface` as a member:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Listener {

    IInterface iInterface;

    public void doStuff(){
        iInterface.printIt();
    }
}
```

Now, my requirement is to inject either of `ImplementationA.java` or `ImplementationB.java` in the `iInterface` member of `Listener.java` based on certain condition.

After some research I started using the `@Conditional` annotation.
I added two classes `ConditionA.java` and `ConditionB.java`:

```
public class ConditionA implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
public class ConditionB implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I also changed my implementation classes as below(added the `Conditional` annotation):

```
@Component
@Conditional(ConditionA.class)
public class ImplementationA implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationA");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Conditional(ConditionB.class)
public class ImplementationB implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationA");
    }
}
```

This seems to work like a charm for me. Whichever implementation class I need to inject I just return `true` from its corresponding `Condition` class and return `false` from rest of the implementation class's `Condition` class.

However this next part is where I am facing the challenge:
So from the above solution, I was hardcoding the `return true` or `return false` from the `matches` method of the corresponding `Condition` class. What if I need to return a dynamic value based on another component.

Lets say I have a spring `Component` class `MyCustomConfig` which has a member `customFlag` and if this member is set to true, we need to inject ImplementationA.class.
I had tried the below(made the class @Component and also autowired MyCustomConfig):

```
@Component
public class ConditionA implements Condition {
    @Autowired
    MyCustomConfig myCustomConfig;    

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return myCustomConfig.getCustomFlag();
    }
}
```

However this simply does not work. myCustomConfig is not autowired and I get a null pointer exception.

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: how do you instantiate your ConditionA class?

Comment: I'm not actually instantiating ConditionA.class. Spring seems to do it internally when I annonate my ImplementationA class with @Conditional(ConditionA.class)

Comment: I don't actually see that in your code, neither

Comment: @Stultuske What do you not see ?

Comment: Why not implement the Condition by both Implementation A & B and use strategy at runtime to determine the specific instance?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no chance for what you need with the use of `implements Condition`.

If you inspect the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) for `interface Condition` which is what the class that you provide to `@Conditional` should do, in your case `ConditionA` and `ConditionB` it says:

> Conditions must follow the same restrictions as
> BeanFactoryPostProcessor **and take care to never interact with bean
> instances.** For more fine-grained control of conditions that interact
> with @Configuration beans consider implementing the
> ConfigurationCondition interface.

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70351394/7237884) would provide a workaround for you as it mentioned above in documentation that in the case that you want to interfere with other beans you should implement your own custom ConfigurationCondition.

Just check that the phase where this ConfigurationCondition will run will be after the beans that you need are registered

Answer (score 1):

I would register the bean using a configuration class and a `@Bean` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class ImplementationConfig {
    @Bean 
    public IInterface implementation(MyCustomConfig myCustomConfig) {
        if (myCustomConfig.getCustomFlag()) {
           return new ImplementationA();
        } else {
           return new ImplementationB();
        }
    }
}
```

You simply drop the Spring-related annotations in both `ImplementationA` and `ImplementationB`:

```java
public class ImplementationA implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationA");
    }
}
```

```java
public class ImplementationB implements IInterface {
    @Override
    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println("Inside ImplementationA");
    }
}
```

And finally, you can drop the `Condition` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/70351394/7237884 here.

The docs say

```
Conditions must follow the same restrictions as BeanFactoryPostProcessor and take care to never interact with bean instances. For more fine-grained control of conditions that interact with @Configuration beans consider implementing the ConfigurationCondition interface.
```